# Select all checkbox is selecting disabled checkbox in angular?

Tags: angular, primeng

```
<div *ngIf="showLog">
      <!-- <p *ngIf="metricExecutionList

    Blockquote

===null">No Records Found</p> -->
      <div>
    <p-table #dt [value]="metricExecutionList" [loading]="loading" [alwaysShowPaginator]="true" [rows]="20"
      [paginator]="true" [responsive]="true" [(selection)]="selectedValues">
      <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:4%">
            <p-tableHeaderCheckbox (onHeaderCheckboxToggle)="onSelectAll($event)"></p-tableHeaderCheckbox>
          </th>
          <th [pSortableColumn]="'publishdMetricName'" style="width:22%;">
            Metric Group Name
            <p-sortIcon [field]="'publishdMetricName'"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>

          <th [pSortableColumn]="'publishdMemberName'" style="width:18%;">
            Member Name
            <p-sortIcon [field]="'publishdMemberName'"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
          <th [pSortableColumn]="'status'" style="width:10%;">
            Status
            <p-sortIcon [field]="'status'"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
          <th [pSortableColumn]="'publishedCohortEndDate'" style="width:12%;">
            Cohort End Date
            <p-sortIcon [field]="'publishedCohortEndDate'"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>

          <th [pSortableColumn]="'publishedDefinitionEndDate'" style="width:14%;">
            Definition End Date
            <p-sortIcon [field]="'publishedDefinitionEndDate'"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
          <th [pSortableColumn]="'executedDateInfo'" style="width:12%;">
            Executed Date
            <p-sortIcon [field]="'executedDateInfo'"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
          <!-- <th [pSortableColumn]="'publishedDate'" style="width:12%;">
            Published Date
            <p-sortIcon [field]="'publishedDate'"></p-sortIcon>
          </th> -->
          <!-- <th style="width:25%;">
            Publish To
          </th> -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="width"></th>
          <th>
            <input pInputText type="text" style="width:100px"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'publishdMetricName', 'contains')">

            <!-- <p-multiSelect [style]="{'width': '100%'}" [options]="status2" defaultLabel="Select"
              (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, publishdMetricName, 'contains')"></p-multiSelect> -->
          </th>
          <th><input pInputText type="text" style="width:100px"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'publishdMemberName', 'contains')">
          </th>
          <th><input pInputText type="text" style="width:100px"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'status', 'contains')">
          </th>
          <th><input pInputText type="text" style="width:100px"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'publishedCohortEndDate', 'contains')">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input pInputText type="text" style="width:100px"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'publishedDefinitionEndDate', 'contains')">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input pInputText type="text" style="width:100px"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'executedDateInfo', 'contains')">
          </th>
          <!-- <th>
            <input pInputText type="text" style="width:100px"
              (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'publishedDate', 'contains')">
          </th> -->
          <!-- <th></th> -->
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-metricExecutionList>
        <tr>
          <td class="width">
            <p-tableCheckbox [value]="metricExecutionList"
              [disabled]="metricExecutionList.status === 'Initiated' || metricExecutionList.status === 'Queued' || metricExecutionList.status === 'Running'  || metricExecutionList.status === 'Processing'">
            </p-tableCheckbox>
            <!-- && metricExecutionList.status !== 'Running' && metricExecutionList.status !== 'Queued' && metricExecutionList.status !== 'Processing'">
            </p-tableCheckbox> -->
          </td>
          <td title="{{metricExecutionList.publishdMetricName}}">
            {{metricExecutionList.publishdMetricName }}</td>
          <td title="{{metricExecutionList.publishdMemberName}}">
            {{metricExecutionList.publishdMemberName }}</td>
          <td title="{{metricExecutionList.status}}">
            {{metricExecutionList.status }}</td>
          <td title="{{metricExecutionList.publishedCohortEndDate}}">
            {{metricExecutionList.publishedCohortEndDate }}
          </td>
          <td title="{{metricExecutionList.publishedDefinitionEndDate}}">
            {{metricExecutionList.publishedDefinitionEndDate }}</td>
          <td title="{{metricExecutionList.executedDateInfo }}">
            {{metricExecutionList.executedDateInfo }}</td>
          <!-- <td title="{{metricExecutionList.publishedDate  | date:'short'}}">
            {{metricExecutionList.publishedDate | date:'short'}}</td> -->
          <!-- <td>
            <p-radioButton value="DM" label="DM" [(ngModel)]="metricExecutionList.publishedTo">
            </p-radioButton>
            &nbsp;
            <p-radioButton value="Reports" label="Reports" [(ngModel)]="metricExecutionList.publishedTo">
            </p-radioButton>&nbsp;
            <p-radioButton  value="Both" label="Both" [(ngModel)]="metricExecutionList.publishedTo">
            </p-radioButton>
          </td> -->
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="emptymessage" let-columns>
        <tr>
          <td [attr.colspan]="7" class="align-center">
            No records found
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
    <br>
    <div class="p-grid">
      <!-- <div class="p-col-6 p-md-10 p-lg-10"></div> -->

      <div class="p-col-10 p-md-10 p-lg-10 text-right" [hidden]="true">
        <span><b>Publish To</b> : </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <p-radioButton value="DM" label="Data Mart" [(ngModel)]="publishedTo">
        </p-radioButton>
        &nbsp;
        <p-radioButton value="Reports" label="Reports" [(ngModel)]="publishedTo">
        </p-radioButton>&nbsp;
        <p-radioButton value="Both" label="Both" [(ngModel)]="publishedTo">
        </p-radioButton>
      </div>
      <div class="p-col-12 p-md-12 p-lg-12 text-right">
        <button pButton type="button" title="Publish" [disabled]="selectedValues.length === 0" class="tdStyle"
          label="Publish" (click)="onClickPublish()"></button>&nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is implementation for the `selectAll` method missing, but I can see you are using the `disabled` property of the `p-checkbox` component.
However that property can only be read via a reference to that component, which you don't have in your code.

Better approach would be, using an Angular [ReactiveForm](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and setting the disabled attribute on the form control.

Comment: I didn't get you clearly .Can you please edit my code and reply me so, may be i get idea.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.ngAddForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'metricName': new FormControl(''),
      'memberName': new FormControl(''),
      'cohortEndDate': new FormControl(''),
      'definitionEndDate': new FormControl(''),
      'fromDate': new FormControl(''),
      'toDate': new FormControl(''),
    });
    this.getAllPublishedMetrics();
    this.getMetricNamesList();
    this.getCohortEndDateList();
    this.getDefinitionEndDateList();
    this.getOrganizationsByClient(this.userService.clientName);
  }

Comment: above is my ts code for form controls..